# .htaccess remove slash it end of url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i have one strange situation, i am rewriting file name to url without extension in it , am using same .htaccess rules for both files however in one slash (/) it end appear i do not know why in first one it not appear , and that slash it end creating problem for me because site assets url effected and giving me 404 ,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule    ^stars/?$    stars.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^projects/?$    projects.php    [NC,L]
```

so first one is ok it land on site.com/stars   while second one land on site.com/projects/

so any idea how to remove that / from projects url

Comment: Are there any other rules? You can also fix your assets url without removing the trailing slash , just include the following line in head section of your webpage . **<base href="/">**

Comment: @starkeen i updated rules set  thanks for base href i forget about it ,

Comment: Clear your browser cache and retest. Is there any directory with name `projects`?

Comment: @anubhava   ya there is projects name directory too

Comment: Ok, in that case trailing slash is added by Apache for security reasons to avoid showing directory content.

Comment: ok thanks ............